# Access Policy Creation for Access packages in AD using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have this code that created an access review for the access packages in Entitlement management in Azure AD. I am able to create a quaterly Access review but I am unable to create an "annually" one

Code:

```
accessReviewSettings = @{
        isEnabled = $true
        recurrenceType = "quarterly"
        reviewerType = "Manager"
        startDateTime = Get-Date
        durationInDays = 25
        reviewers = @(
        @{
        "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.singleUser"
                        id            = $fallbackApprover.Id
                        description   = $fallbackApprover.DisplayName
                        isBackup      = $true
                        }
        )
    }
```

Comment: Access reviews in `Ms graph` only `dayOfMonth`, interval, and type **(weekly, absoluteMonthly)** properties are supported. Refer the [Ms doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/recurrencepattern?view=graph-rest-beta#properties)

Answer (score 0):

> I am able to create a quaterly Access review but I am unable to create an "annually" one.

There is a limitation, when creating access policies for access packages. You cannot use the annually recurrence type if you want to enable access reviews for your access package. This is because access reviews are not supported for annually recurrence type. If you try to create an access policy with this combination, you will get a below error message.

[image]

The only properties that are supported for access reviews are **dayOfMonth**, **interval**, and **type**. The **type** property can have either `weekly` or `absoluteMonthly` as its value, you can check the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/recurrencepattern?view=graph-rest-beta#properties) for more details about access reviews.